# How to add a script to all my visual pages?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am using for the very first time salesforce as backend.
I need to add the same script to all the visualpages.

Is there a way to achieve this other than copy the same thing to all the visual pages?
A tool for importing the same script for instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I presume you don't want to copy the whole script?
Somehow you still have to tell the VF page to use the script. I think the best practice would be to "pack" the script into a file (if this is JavaScript file the extension would be .js) and upload the file as a Static resource. You can then call the script on every VF page like so:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NAME_OF_YOUR_SCRIPT)}"></apex:includeScript>
```

Is that what you had in mind? :)

Cheers, G.

Comment: thanks for your response, not exactly. I dont want to add 100 times this tag but I would like to automize it

Comment: I see. What kind of pages do you have? Do you use the same custom controller in all of those pages? Maybe it would be a good idea to add the script or the tag via apex?

Comment: it's an </apex:page> containing html, I dont know if all of them share the same controller

Comment: Do you add a tag "controller=STH" or "standardController=STH" to your first <apex:page> badge?